# iterating through a list (float is not subscriptible)

Tags: python

I am currently trying to complete this code. I keep getting 'float' object is not subscriptable. I have created a list of random numbers up to n and I want to use that list to find the sum of those numbers while indexing j at 0,2,4,6.

```
def summer(n):
    list1 = []
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):#making a random number up to n in a list
        i = random()
        list1.append(i)

    for j in list1[::2]:
        sum = sum + (math.sin(j) * math.cos(j[j+1]))

    return sum
```

Comment: Your question has already been answered by @Gamopo but I wanted to point out something else you are doing that does not really make sense. In the first for loop that is using the index `i`you should not be assigning to `i` and overwriting it. Instead you could use another temporary variable, or just do `list1.append(random())`

Answer (score 2):

You are accesing `j` which is a number as if it was a list here:

```
sum = sum + (math.sin(j) * math.cos(j[j+1]))
```

To solve this, you could:

```
for j in range(0,len(list1),2):
     mysum = mysum + (math.sin(list1[j]) * math.cos(list1[j+1]))
```

I'll also recommend, to change `sum`'s name, since it is an reserved word in Python.

Comment: how would i access it as a number?

Comment: Thank you, I see what you did. that makes a lot more sense now.But why do you iterate j?

Comment: @Joeyhoward98 I iterate the index instead of the element, this way I access the element using the index on the list

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = sum + (math.sin(j) * math.cos(j[j+1]))
```

Use print(j), your 'j' is int not a list, so you can do j[j+1].

What do you want to do here `math.cos(j[j+1])` ??